# Initializing swift subclass from objc class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a custom UITableViewController class in Objective C named "A", and made a subclass from it in Swift named "B".

Class "A" have two initializer, a simple "init" and the "initWithCoder" method.
I've made an other initializer in the class "B", which is like "init(stuff:Stuff)" and it calls a super.init()

Now it seems when the super.init() is called and the class "A" init calls it's own [super init] its trying to call the default initializers of UITableViewController on class "B".

The problem is, if I implement the missing methods, I have to initialize the local "stuff" object which is stored in class "B" and it's already set by the custom init I made.

Is it normal that the default TableView inits are called?

How should I build my classes to keep the "stuff" object, if the other methods called?

```
//Abstract example
//Obj-c class

@interface A : UITableViewController
@end

@implementation A
- (instancetype) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    // This is where the tableview inits called on class B
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}
@end 


//Swift class

class B : A {
    var stuff : Stuff

    init(stuff : Stuff) {
        self.stuff = stuff
        super.init()
    }
    /*
    // It works if these methods are here, but I must initialize the "stuff"
    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        self.stuff = Stuff()
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewStyle) {
        self.stuff = Stuff()
        super.init(style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
    }
    */
}
```

Edit:
Okay so I learned how initializer inheritance works, and I must override all if I want to use one. Still, I don't understand why are they all getting called from the parent class after one init?

Comment: Can you post a simple code example? Your setup steps are hard to follow.

Comment: Sure, just added a basic example.